# how to extract uncommon data between two different data columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is data.

```
 col="a","b","c","d"
 col1="a","b","c","g","q"
```

My desired output is

```
 'd','g','q'
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! What have you attempted so far to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^` i.e [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) here.

```
col="a","b","c","d"
col1="a","b","c","g","q"

print(set(col)^set(col1))
# {'d', 'g', 'q'}
```

Or use `set.symmetric_difference` suggested by [@timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb) in the comments

```
set(col).symmetric_difference(col1)
```